# Matcher not finding matches

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract the numbers in the following string:

`09/29/2014`

I am currently using the code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(startDatepicker);

String startYear = m.group(3);
String startMonth = m.group(1);
String startDay = m.group(2);
```

`startDatepicker` contains: `09/29/2014`

However, I am not receiving any matches. I also tried escaping the forward slashes with `\\` but that also didn't work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you could access the matched groups, you need to call `find()` on the matcher, and check that it has found a match:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(startDatepicker);
if (!m.find()) {
    return;
}
String startYear = m.group(3);
String startMonth = m.group(1);
String startDay = m.group(2);
```

The call of `m.find()` positions the matcher on the first match.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/cy9Pdw)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `find()` to iterate through your match groups.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(startDatepicker);
while (m.find()) {
  ...
}
```

The `find()` method searches for occurrences of the regex in the input passed to `p.matcher()`. If multiple matches can be found, this method will find the first, and then move to the next match for each subsequent call.